# Keepalived pidof error

Tags: keepalived, ubuntu-22.04

I have configured keepalived on 2 Ubuntu 22.04 machines and it all seems to be working.

But in the status (systemctl status keepalived.service) I see some lines which concern me.

> Feb 28 09:36:28 host pidof[2442791]: can't read from 2442790/stat

I am clueless where this is coming from or what to do about it

In the keepalived config we check via script and in this script there are to checks. 1 is a ping to the gateway to check if we have network connectivity. The second check is to see if a process is running (using pidof). The check is done every 2 seconds.

Config keepalived:

```
    ! Configuration File for keepalived


global_defs {
   notification_email {
     system@some.net
   }
   enable_traps
   notification_email_from root@host.some.net
   smtp_server x.x.x.x
   smtp_connect_timeout 30
   vrrp_skip_check_adv_addr
   enable_script_security
   max_auto_priority 1
   disable_local_igmp
   vrrp_rt_priority 50
}


vrrp_script vlan303_check {
       script "/etc/keepalived/scripts/vlan303/checkscript.sh"
       interval 2                     # check every 2 seconds
       fall 2
       rise 2
}

vrrp_script vlan333_check {
       script "/etc/keepalived/scripts/vlan333/checkscript.sh"
       interval 2                     # check every 2 seconds
       fall 2
       rise 2
}

vrrp_instance VLAN303 {
    state MASTER
    interface ens192
    virtual_router_id 151
    priority 110
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass xxxx
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        xx.xx.xx.xx
    }

 track_script {
        vlan303_check
    }

    notify /etc/keepalived/scripts/notify.sh
    notify_stop /etc/keepalived/scripts/notify.sh
}

vrrp_instance VLAN333 {
    state BACKUP
    interface ens224
    virtual_router_id 171
    priority 100
    advert_int 1
    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass xxxxx
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        xx.xx.xx.xx
    }
    track_script {
        vlan333_check
    }
    notify /etc/keepalived/scripts/notify.sh
    notify_stop /etc/keepalived/scripts/notify.sh
}
```

Scripts are executed as keepalived_script (user is added to the system with no bash (/sbin/nologin)

I have checked that the script is correctly executed. (and it does)

So could it be that the checkscript sometimes does not get the pid of the process and therefor giving this error?

Or maybe this is caused by not having a shell for the user keepalived_script ?